# c# drag drop DataObject

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

Im using C# 2.0 and i have created an explorer tree that i can drag information from into a windows form. right now, when i drag from the treeview that im using, it performs `DoDragDrop(selectedpath, DragDropEffects.Copy);`

When i catch the event in my mainform, it is listed as a string. I am able to make this work but i want it to perform the same way that it does if i were to drag a file from my windows explorer window which is as follows

```
   Array name = (Array)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        // Ensure that the list item index is contained in the data.
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {

            Object item = (object)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));

            // Perform drag-and-drop, depending upon the effect.
            if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Copy ||
                e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
            {

                //// Insert the item.
                //if (indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop != ListBox.NoMatches)
                //    ListDragTarget.Items.Insert(indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop, item);
                //else
                //    ListDragTarget.Items.Add(item);

            }
        }
```

i have tried to do DoDragDrop(new DataObject(selectedfile),DragDropEffects.Copy) but that doesnt work.

Comment: At least tell the guy why you down voted his question!

Comment: thanks. I have searched for an answer but dont seem to be finding it.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question.  +1

Answer (score 1):

`DoDragDrop` and `DragDropEffects.Copy` will not take action on your drive, not unless you tell them to. What `DragDropEffects.Copy` does is actually copy the object *in the program*, not the file itself.

See the documentation on [`DragDropEffects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

You'll need to manage the [`OnDragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ondragdrop%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event and use a copy function like [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thats what i did. I found a way to make it work finally by doing the following