# How do I drag files from my application to the Desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# / WPF / .NET - Drag and drop to Desktop / Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/c-wpf-net-drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer)

I've managed to drag files from the Desktop into my WPF application.  Now I want to drag them back out.

This code does not work.  Everything looks right (the cursor turns into a +) but the file is not copied.

```
listBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("drag leave");

    // changing this line to: var data = "a string"; works for text dragging
    var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filePath);

    // also tried DragDropEffects.Copy with no success
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(item, data, DragDropEffects.All);
};
```

Any ideas?

Very similar question here but I don't understand their answer: [c# drag drop DataObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073953/c-drag-drop-dataobject)

Thanks,

Neal

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    string[] array = { filePath };
    var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, array);
    listBox1.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```